# Blade template and radio buttons - select first in foreach loop

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have the following Blade template entry, which creates (as part of a table row) a column of radio buttons.

I want to have only the first radio genereated selected, and I want to do this via the PHP, no js post page load.

How do I check if this is the "first" entry in my collection and thus place the string `checked` as an attribute in the HTML? My latest code permutation is below, but it does not work.

```
@foreach ($organisationsOwned as $organisationOwned)
    <tr class="organisations-table">
        <td><input type="radio" name="organisations" id="{!! $organisationOwned->id !!}" @if ($organisationsOwned{0}) {!! "checked" !!} @endif></td>
        <td>{!! $organisationOwned->org_title !!}</td>
        <td>{!! $organisationOwned->plan_title !!}</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">{!! currency_format($organisationOwned->gst_amount) !!}</td>
        <td style="text-align: right;">{!! $organisationOwned->subscription_ends_at !!}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

More precisely, here's the line for the input:

```
<input type="radio" name="organisations" id="{!! $organisationOwned->id !!}" @if ($organisationsOwned{0}) {!! "checked" !!} @endif>
```

I have tried variations such as:

```
{{ head($organisationsOwned) ? checked : '' }}>
```

and

```
{{ $organisationsOwned{0} ? checked : '' }}>
```

and even [this suggestion shown as a working model](http://laraveldaily.com/blade-foreach-firstlast-item-of-the-array/) of my question:

```
@if ($organisationOwned == reset($organisationsOwned)) checked @endif
```

Thanks and happy new year!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you did not specify keys for the elements of **$organisationsOwned** you can use the element's index to determine if it's the first one:

```
@foreach($organisationsOwned as $index => $organisationOwned)
  ...
  <td><input type="radio" name="organisations" id="{!! $organisationOwned->id !!}" @if (!$index) {!! "checked" !!} @endif></td>
  ...
@endforeach
```

Comment: hi @jedrzej.kurylo, may 2016 be your year my friend! Thank you!