# Laravel 5.2 named route usage with variable parameter

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-5

I have a route like this:

```
// Open New Subscription page
Route::get('/account/subscriptions/create/{menu}', ['uses' => 'Subscriptions\SubscriptionController@create', 'as' => 'subscription.create']);
```

In my blade template I use the named route like this:

```
<a href="{!! route('organisations.index') . "/p11-c3" !!}">
```

But this format does not work.

How do I pass the variable menu a value while still using the named route (rather than hard coding a `url` in the `href`)?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can pass your route parameters as the second argument to **route()** helper:

```
<a href="{!! route('organisations.index', ['menu' => 'p11-c3']) !!}">
```

Make sure you're using correct names. Your routing defines **subscription.create** route while your template refers to **organisations.index** route.

Comment: Hi @jedrzej.kurylo, you ROCK! Thanks!! And pushing my friendship, do you have a suggestion for this Q? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34554021/blade-template-and-radio-buttons-select-first-in-foreach-loop